recording and playing audio in kivy for android
"Hello,
I'm planning to develop a Kivy app for Android where I can record my voice and listen to it. For recording my voice, I'm utilizing the following class:
class MyRecorder():

def __init__(self):
    self.MediaRecorder = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder')
    self.AudioSource = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$AudioSource')
    self.OutputFormat = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$OutputFormat')
    self.AudioEncoder = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$AudioEncoder')
    self.mRecorder = self.MediaRecorder()

def startRecording(self):
    now = datetime.now()
    self.dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") \
        .replace(" ", "").replace(":", "").replace("/", "")
    if platform=='android':
        ss = SharedStorage()
        primary_ext_storage = ss.get_cache_dir()
    else:
        primary_ext_storage = 'assets/files/'
    self.path = primary_ext_storage + '/{}.mp3'.format(self.dt_string)
    self.mRecorder.setAudioSource(self.AudioSource.MIC)
    self.mRecorder.setOutputFormat(self.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
    self.mRecorder.setOutputFile(self.path)
    self.mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(self.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC)
    self.mRecorder.prepare()
    self.mRecorder.start()

def stopRecording(self):
    self.mRecorder.stop()
    self.mRecorder.release()

To play the recorded voice, I've implemented the following class:
class VoiceChatBubble(MDCard):
src = StringProperty()
msg = StringProperty()
time = StringProperty()
sender = StringProperty()
profile = StringProperty()
isRead = OptionProperty('waiting', options=['read', 'delivered', 'waiting'])

def __init__(self, show_error, **kwargs):
    self.show_error= show_error
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

def loadSong(self):
    try:
        self.sound= SoundLoader.load(self.src)
        self.slider.max = self.sound.length
        self.current_time.text = "00:00"
        self.slider.value = 0
        self.isResume = False
    except Exception as e:
        # print('hi')
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt, exception=e: self.show_error(f'Errrror: {exception}'))

def play(self):
    if self.play_icon.icon == 'pause-circle-outline':
        self.pause()
    elif self.isResume:
        self.resume()
    else:
        self.playSong()

def playSong(self):
    if self.sound:
        try:
            self.sound.play()
            self.updateProcessbarEvent = Clock.schedule_interval(self.updateSlider, 1)
            self.updateTimeEvent = Clock.schedule_interval(self.setTime, 1)
            self.play_icon.icon= 'pause-circle-outline'
            self.isResume = False     
        except Exception as e:
            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt, exception=e: self.show_error(f'Error: {exception}'))
        
def pause(self):
    if self.sound:
        try:
            self.currtentSeekTime = self.sound.get_pos()
            self.sound.stop()
            self.play_icon.icon= 'play-outline'
            self.updateProcessbarEvent.cancel()
            self.updateTimeEvent.cancel()
            self.isResume = True 
        except Exception as e:
            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt, exception=e: self.show_error(f'Error: {exception}'))
        
def resume(self):
    if self.sound:
        try:
            self.isResume = False
            self.sound.play()
            self.sound.seek(self.currtentSeekTime)
            self.play_icon.icon= 'pause-circle-outline'
            self.updateProcessbarEvent = Clock.schedule_interval(self.updateSlider, 1)
            self.updateTimeEvent = Clock.schedule_interval(self.setTime, 1)  
        except Exception as e:
            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt, exception=e: self.show_error(f'Error: {exception}'))
        
def updateSlider(self, fuck):
    self.slider.value +=1
    if self.slider.value>=self.slider.max:
        self.slider.value=0
        self.current_time.text = "00:00"
        self.second=0
        self.pause()
        self.isResume=False

def setTime(self, fuck):
    currtentTime = strftime("%M:%S", gmtime(self.slider.value))
    self.current_time.text = currtentTime

def seek(self):
    if self.sound:
        self.sound.seek(self.slider.value)

While recording my voice using AudioEncoder.AMR_NB, OutputFormat.THREE_GPP and saving it with the .m4a extension, I'm able to save the voice successfully. However, I encounter a 'nonetype object has no attribute length' error when I try to access self.sound.length. On the other hand, when I opt for AudioEncoder.HE_AAC, OutputFormat.MPEG_4 and save it with the .mp3 extension, I receive a length of 0 in the output of the self.sound.length line."
i can not play sound in neither ways. but when i open the recorded voice in a another player i can play it successfully
